# Google Chart API Gantt Chart Dependency Issues

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I started creating a simple gantt chart and all was going good until the API went crazy. I have two streams of development, when both streams are done I'm planning on doing a "Full Test". One stream finishes a lot later than the first stream. The "Full Test" can only happen after both streams are finished.

The google chart API calculates the "Full Test" start date to be immediately after the first stream is complete. Even though it draws an array from the end of the second stream to "Full Test".

Any ideas on how I can fix this (without setting a hard coded start time for "Full Test")?

I defined the chart using the following data:

```
['Info', "Info Gathering", "planning", new Date(2015, 8, 1), null, daysToMilliseconds(4), 0, ''],
['Setup1', "Setup 1", "setup", null, null, daysToMilliseconds(4), 0, 'Info'],
['Setup2', "Setup 2", "setup", new Date(2016, 0, 4), null, daysToMilliseconds(4), 0, 'Info'],
['Dev2', "Dev 2", "dev", null, null, daysToMilliseconds(90), 0, "Setup2"],
['Test1', "Testing 1", "test", null, null, daysToMilliseconds(4), 0, 'Setup1'],
['Test2', "Testing 2", "test", null, null, daysToMilliseconds(4), 0, 'Dev2'],
['FullTest', "Test Everything", "test", null, null, daysToMilliseconds(4), 0, 'Test1,Test2']
```

You can see my code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/v8qyjq2g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's just a bug, maybe you've noticed this:
***`The Gantt chart is in beta and may be undergoing substantial revisions in future Google Charts releases.`***

e.g. when I switch the rows 2 and 3 I get the (I think so) [**desired result**](https://jsfiddle.net/15skgc0L/), but the order of the rows shouldn't matter.

Comment: I'll wait a little longer for it to mature I suppose. Thanks for taking the time to look over what I was doing.